# How can you have a keyboard language that is accessible, but not through left-alt+shift?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

For example, I currently have 2 keyboard languages: English and Hebrew. I want to add a 3rd language: Greek, that I can access through some hotkey or via windows+space. Although, I don't want for it to pop up when I switch through the other 2 languages using left-alt+shift. If this is possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

They keyboard options have 2 different settings:

- Keyboard Language, controlled by <kbd>L CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L SHIFT</kbd>
- Keyboard Layout, controlled by <kbd>L ALT</kbd>-<kbd>L SHIFT</kbd>

Each Keyboard layout can have one or more languages.

If you set the english keyboard layout on the Hebrew language settings, and have the greek layout on the greek language setting, you can use <kbd>L CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L SHIFT</kbd> to toggle between english and hebrew, and use <kbd>L ALT</kbd>-<kbd>L SHIFT</kbd> to switch to greek and back to the previous one.

<sup>*Applicable to Windows 2000 and up*</sup>

Comment: You don't seem to be able to set an English keyboard layout on the Hebrew language settings. It seems like for every language you can add different layouts for the same language only.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you can type Hebrew using the US International keyboard layout. But if you can't, then to my knowledge, there is no way to accomplish what you want.